# Get jave files recursively and store in array list

Tags: java, arraylist, file-io

I am trying to get all `.java-files` from a given `directory` and all its `subdirectories`. Ive come up with a recursive solution that `prints` out all the files I want, but my actual goal is to store all `paths` into an `array` so I can work with them. Storing them is where I struggle at the moment. This is my code:

```
public static ArrayList<String> getJavaFiles(Path path) throws CodeValidationException {


    ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();

    DirectoryStream<Path> stream = null;
    try {

        stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(path);
        for (Path entry : stream) {
            if (Files.isRegularFile(entry)) {
                if(entry.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".java")) {

                    boolean isRegularExecutableFile = Files.isRegularFile(entry)
                            && Files.isReadable(entry);
                    //&& Files.isExecutable(entry) -> not working

                    if(isRegularExecutableFile) { 
                        System.out.println("path: " + entry);
                        files.add(entry.getFileName().toString());
                    }
                };

            } else if (Files.isDirectory(entry)) {
                getJavaFiles(entry);
            }

        }

        return files;


    } catch (IOException e) {

        throw new CodeValidationException(String.format("error reading folder %s: %s", path, e.getMessage()), e);

    } finally {
        if(stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Edit:**

Here is an example:

This is from `getJavaFiles`:

> path: /Users/chris/Uni Bamberg/3. Semester/AJP/Assignment1/Assignment1/src/de/uniba/wiai/dsg/ajp/assignment1/Main.java
>
> path: /Users/chris/Uni Bamberg/3.
>   Semester/AJP/Assignment1/Assignment1/src/de/uniba/wiai/dsg/ajp/assignment1/validation/impl/SimpleCodeValidator.java
>
> path: /Users/chris/Uni Bamberg/3.
>   Semester/AJP/Assignment1/Assignment1/src/de/uniba/wiai/dsg/ajp/assignment1/validation/impl/TaskValidation.java
>
> path: /Users/chris/Uni Bamberg/3.
>   Semester/AJP/Assignment1/Assignment1/src/de/uniba/wiai/dsg/ajp/assignment1/validation/CodeValidationException.java
>
> path: /Users/chris/Uni Bamberg/3.
>   Semester/AJP/Assignment1/Assignment1/src/de/uniba/wiai/dsg/ajp/assignment1/validation/ValidationResult.java
>
> path: /Users/chris/Uni Bamberg/3.
>   Semester/AJP/Assignment1/Assignment1/src/de/uniba/wiai/dsg/ajp/assignment1/validation/Warning.java
>
> path: /Users/chris/Uni Bamberg/3.
>   Semester/AJP/Assignment1/Assignment1/src/de/uniba/wiai/dsg/ajp/assignment1/validation/CodeValidator.java
>
> path: /Users/chris/Uni Bamberg/3.
>   Semester/AJP/Assignment1/Assignment1/src/de/uniba/wiai/dsg/ajp/assignment1/validation/ValidationTask.java
>
> path: /Users/chris/Uni Bamberg/3.
>   Semester/AJP/Assignment1/Assignment1/src/de/uniba/wiai/dsg/ajp/assignment1/validation/WarningType.java
>
> path: /Users/chris/Uni Bamberg/3. Semester/AJP/inputFile.java

But when printing out the `ArrayList` which I get from the function all I get is:

```
for(int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {   
    System.out.print(files.get(i)); 
}
```

> /Users/chris/Uni Bamberg/3. Semester/AJP/inputFile.java

Comment: Please give us your output. Because your code seems alright. Maybe you have only one `.java` file.

Comment: @Omid.N edited my question. Dont know if that really helps you

Comment: It seems you **are** finding the right paths and you **are** adding them to your ArrayList. So if you are printing it correctly, it is impossible that you not get the right outputs. Also, you should put your return statement after `finally` block.

Comment: @Omid.N check out my question again, i posted how I print it. And I cant put the return statement after the finally block as it is `unreachable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not work because you are just checking the first directory and you don't add the files in subdirectories. In your `else-if` you are calling `getJavaFiles(entry)` again but you are not adding the list returned from it to your existing list:

```
else if (Files.isDirectory(entry)) {
            getJavaFiles(entry);
    }
```

You can add them to your list like this :

```
else if (Files.isDirectory(entry)) {
            files.addAll(getJavaFiles(entry));
     }
```